# Dagger2, destruction of a custom scoped module

Tags: android, dagger-2

While using [Dagger2](http://google.github.io/dagger/) I defined `@ActivityScope`

```
    @Scope
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface ActivityScope { }
```

and instantiated corresponding `ActivityModule` in `Activity.onCreate()` as following.

```
    mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
        .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
        .build();
```

By doing this, I attach module's lifecycle to the lifecycle of the activity. All module's instances will be created for every new activity. In that respect everything works just fine.

My actual question is what is the right/best way to destroy module's components (e.g. remove service callbacks etc.) when activity gets actually destroyed? Does `Dagger2` itself offers anything for this?

Answer (score 4):

`@Scope` annotations provide both compilation time validation, and on module provider methods, it makes Dagger2 create a scoped provider which will allow the creation of only one instance per scope within that particular component.

It doesn't really do anything more than that, so if you need to explicitly unregister callbacks that are within your activity, then you should probably inject these dependencies within your activity, and manually unregister them yourself in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: That was my fist idea too. I don't even need to inject instances, I can access them directly through the component. But this would mean writing boilerplate code in onDestroy(), which I would like to avoid.

Comment: My other idea is using a bus... Register them in the constructor, then send out the event for the corresponding activity onDestroy() which makes them all unsubscribe and unregister.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it. This means Dagger doesn't support any kind of module lifecycle out of the box. Ideal solution would be to call onDestroy() only once and the rest code down to the onDestroy() of every instance gets generated. Is there any extension API in Dagger2 for writing such a generator?

Comment: I somewhat wonder if maybe you should just provide `Activity` as a parameter in the provider method, and just add all your subscribed stuff to a `List<?>` in the Activity which the Activity iterates and unsubscribes in `onDestroy()`

Comment: This is an interesting option. At least this this something I can already do. I have also opened a ticker asking what can be done to add some kind of lifecycle to the module. Let's see what they answer.